# bash: ngc: command not found

Tags: bash, angular

I'm using @angular/compiler-cli to build my ng2 app in aot mode. When I input 'ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json' in my bash window, I get 'bash: ngc: command not found'. However, when I use 'node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json' instead, it works. I googled for serval times but didn't get any usfull information. Can any give me a hand? Thx!

Comment: My node version is 5.0.0 and npm version is 3.3.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you need to put ngc in your path:

```
echo $PATH
```

Do you see ngc in binary in your path?

If not:

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/ngc
```

To make it permanent add to .bash_profile

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/ngc
```

Comment: I didn't find it in my $PATH, I'll add it. Thx

Comment: so what is the path to ngc?

Comment: @ConquerorsHaki Depends on installation, but you can find anything on linux using : `find / -name ngc`

Comment: if I am in my projects directory and run `npm install @angular/cli` where will I found ngc then?

Comment: I am using angular 6 and I found that after installing the modules as described in [ngx-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/aot.md), the file tsconfig-aot.json did not exist;however, a file named tsconfig.json did. So, I ran the following command to get this to work. I am not certain if it is correct: `node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to change the slash to 'backslash' on windows and it worked for me:

```
node_modules\\.bin\ngc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set it globally, you can specify an absolut path in your angular-project, just make sure that you delete this part of the path when you don't use it anymore.

ngc is in node_modules/.bin, so depending on where you want to use ngc you can export the path like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:../../../node_modules/.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

To run commands located into the `node_modules` folder of your project, without installing them globally (operation that will make the `ngc` command work in any system folder), you can use this command:

```
ngx ncc <options>
```

Basically `ngx` is a shortcut that executes any command located in `node_modules` bin folder.